# Как выводить картинки картинки подходящего размера но сохраняя пропорции HTML?

Tags: html

Я вывожу картинки но они должны вписываться в форму при этом хочу сохранять ее пропорции что б не шакалило. Есть ли возможность это сделать и если да то как?

Comment: object-fit и/или aspect-ratio

Comment: @UserTest013 Спасибо <3